# Requests and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to get some information from a website but i keep getting as a result `None` . what could be the problem?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


theurl = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q;_ylt=AwrXoCG17EBXRkgAvg.TmYlQ;_ylu=X3oDMTEycDYzNmdzBGNvbG8DZ3ExBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDVklEMDZfMQRzZWMDc2M-?s=" + "AAPL"
thepage = requests.get(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage.content,"html.parser")
textfind = soup.find('span',{"class":"time_rtq_tracker"})
print(textfind)
```

Comment: There is no such `span` in the HTML as parsed by `html.parser`.

Comment: Take into account that your browser runs any JavaScript code a page references, while downloading the source with requests does not. Are you certain that the `span` you are looking for is there in the initial HTML or is it added by JavaScript code running after the page has loaded?

Comment: i believe it is part of the page html but idk how to tell. http://finance.yahoo.com/q;_ylt=AwrXoCG17EBXRkgAvg.TmYlQ;_ylu=X3oDMTEycDYzNmdzBGNvbG8DZ3ExBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDVklEMDZfMQRzZWMDc2M-?s=AAPL    . this is the link, i just inpect element in the price of the stock

Comment: Sure, but `'time_rtq_tracker' in thepage.content` is `False`. Use your browser development tools to see what else is happening in that page when loaded. Perhaps AJAX requests are sent, for example.

Comment: im pretty new to this so idk how to tell or how to fix it

Comment: Perhaps previous posts on Yahoo Finance and BeautifulSoup help; [search for `[python] beautifulsoup finance.yahoo.com`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+beautifulsoup+finance.yahoo.com). See what others have already come up with.

Comment: ok, thanks. much appreciated

Comment: Strange I can not see time_rtq_tracker in the page source but I can see time_rtq_ticker are you sure you have not misspelled it?

Comment: oh wow that was it. i have been looking for that solution for hours now, thanks for noticing